# After deleting files under 'view_preprocessed' folder they dont appear again when reloading site

Tags: magento2, theme, css, less

I'm testing some small LESS changes in my theme. After every change I delete the contents inside:

```
pub/static/frontend/mytheme
```

and

```
var/view_preprocessed
```

Then I reload my site and the contents of `var/view_processed` (css and source folders) are **not** created so the new LESS changes aren't applied. However the site loads fine with the previous LESS settings.

After visiting 10-15 pages the css and source folders are created again and I can see my changes finally.

I constantly delete the Magento cache so thats not the issue. I've also set Firefox and Chrome to not save cookies, history, etc. Permissions have been set to **777** to discard that possible cause.

Why dont the contents of `var/view_preprocessed` folder get created **right after** the first reloading of my site?

Comment: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 2):

You can't get **`view_processed`**  folder until you deploy the content in site.

You must use deployment command to regenarate the `view_processed` folder.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Now you can check inside `var` folder.

Now `view_processed` folder is appear.

Comment: I'm in development mode?  can I delete view_processed? CLI says deploy is not required for dev mode

Comment: No for deployment its not required

Answer (score 1):

delete all folder inside `<magento-root>/var/*` because var/generation folder also cached something.

delete var/* is not a problem because when page load its automatically get generated.

then clear you browser cache, load your page.

suppose still the problems remain please follow the below link instruction. don't need to delete every time pub/static/* below link have given idea about this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454314/simple-style-change-does-not-apply/36510694#36510694

have good luck.

Comment: I think the problem is related to browser. Althoguh I set it to not save any cache information, it seems it is still doing it anyways. I have to clear it every time.

Comment: Deleting everything inside /var and pub/static saved my life thanks @bilal

Answer (score 0):

If you enable `developer` mode. Magento 2 come start with default mode

> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Static files in `pub/static/frontend` or `pub/static/adminhtml` will automatic re-generate after reload with clear cache. Reload it severals time
If you modify `requirejs-config` you should remove file in `pub/static/_requirejs` too

Remove files in pub/static will make all your changes updated

Comment: This seems not to be true. As long as there is stuff in view_preprocessed, that one is taken iiuc. Stuff in there does only get updated with static-deploy, even in developer mode (although then static-deploy needs to be called with --force parameter, because magento tells you the files are not used in dev-mode....).

Answer (score -1):

run this command:

```
rm -rf var/* pub/static/*
```

then redeploy static content using the command below:

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f